# Return HTTP 404 response with no content-type?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way in Django to return a HTTP 404 response without a content-type?

I tried `return HttpResponseNotFound()` from my view, but that sends a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Django 4.2, Django will always set a `Content-Type` header on all HTTP responses it generates. If you review [`django.http.response.HttpResponseBase`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.4/django/http/response.py#L117) you'll find that Django supplies a default value for the content type if none is provided.

If you pass `content_type=""` to a response object, I think it will set `b"Content-Type: "` as the header. I don't know if this is what you want and I'm not certain that it's even a valid value for that header.

If you create a subclass of the response object you could create one that will unset the content type after initialization. I think that class would look something like this.

```py
class HttpResponseUntypedNotFound(HttpResponseNotFound):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.headers["Content-Type"]
```